# Bad cursor position in SharePoint 2013 Note Board (FireFox)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, browser-compatibility, bug, firefox

I'm trying to post a note in SharePoint 2013 Note Board (using FireFox 19 version), the mouse cursor goes out of the text input area.

Screenshot: http://www.rodyk.lt/images/2013/04/10/cursordSbh3.png

Any thouts about this issue or reference how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first question is, are you running 32bit or 64bit firefox browser?

2013 only supports 32. Secondly is it the latest version? i think 20 is out now! but i would presume that 19 should be sufficent!

lastly sharepoint is a microsoft product mainly designed and developed to work with IE ;) its only this version (2013) that they have added chrome and ff so it will be buggy at times but shouldnt be with IE :)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc263526.aspx

> The latest Safari, Firefox, and Chrome browsers are supported with
>   “limitations”.

does it happen in other browsers? or only ff!, i know chrome is very similar to FF so its worth giving it a go!
you need to find if its only that browser and if its only happening on your pc or same behivour on other pcs.

last question is have you modified it in any way or is this ootb webpart? if you havent then it seems like a bug that you have spotted, maybe somthing that they missed out when test with ff/chrome against ie, could be related to a css issue with the webpart as chrome its somewhat working but in ff its way off but in ie its fine! this tells me that its a css issue that they missed in their testing phase and you happened to spot the mistake ;) !

Comment: Thanx for a replay, but im not sure about "2013 only supports 64", where can i get more information?

Comment: There are no Firefox 64bit for Windows at this time (only Mac), im using 32bit version which in your given link is marked as Supported. So we have a bug here?

Comment: Chrome has a very close behaviour like Firefox. In Chrome cursor remains in text area, but there are no padding from areas borders contrary to IE. So in this scenario Chrome is quite usable. Problem remains only in Firefox.

Comment: cursor is out of the bounds in all PCs with Firefox

Comment: I'm using ootb webpart. I think its a bug. If you could renew your post with information from our discussion in comments, I'll mark it as an answer. Thanx!

Comment: ammended my answer! ill be deleting other comments to clean up the comments!